# New requirements for iOS app - keep them accessible to users/customers

Tags: ios, app-store

I got an email from Apple that apps now require iOS13 + storyboard for app launch screen for existing apps. (I do not use storyboard for main app functionality)

I have developed a couple swift1/swift2 based for schools a long time ago. (Still works well)

Can I somehow ditch the app store and then provide direct access or download for school pupils?

i.e. is there any way forward to simple keep the apps-as-they-are? Maybe limited download availability?

Or will I have to take plunge back into app-building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement of a Storyboard launch screen is only when you need to submit an app update. If you are not wanting to update your app any more, then it won’t stop working because of this new requirement.

Regarding distribution outside of the App Store, you could use Adhoc distribution which requires you to know the device ID’s of the devices you want to install it to.

Comment: Are you sure? In the email states there is a deadline? (But if that deadline refers to if one wants to make updates without the storyboard launch screen - then that is great news)

Comment: Yes I’m positive. The headline on Apples own press release is “Deadline for App Updates has been extended”. It just if you want to submit an update, it needs to adhere to these new rules. Apps already on the App Store will not just stop working.